# Finding the nearest neighbours for a subset of samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I have a dataset of about 3 million samples (each with just 3 features). I'm using scikit's `sklearn.neighbors` module - specifically `radius_neighbor_graph` - to find which samples fall within a small radius of a specific sample.

This works fine, but unsurprisingly it's really, really slow to compute this graph.

It's also very wasteful, because I only ever need to know the neighbors for a small subset of my samples (~ 100,000 of them) - and I know this subset in advance.

So... is there any way of being more efficient by calculating the neighbours within a given radius for just this subset of samples? It seems like it should be simple, but I can't think of an easy way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the task of creating a radius-neighborhood-graph involves reading the N by N distance-matrix associated to your dataset. Since distance matrices have nice properties you can save some time, but still complexity lies somewhere in O(N^2). Here N is the number of data points in your data set X.

So one could say, that only a small number of n < N points are of interest as the center of a neighborhood, but the majority of points are just interesting as neighbors. This would result in an n by N distance matrix, where row i contains the distances of data point i to each other data point j, 1 <= i <= n, 1 <= j <= N. But this "distance matrix" has none of the desirable properties of a normal distance matrix (it is not even a square matrix), that you could use to speed up the process of creating an epsilon-neighborhood-graph.

Therefore I don't think that you find a predefined function for your case. If you want to build one your own, the steps should be as follows: Let X be your data set and i be the data point of interest.

1. Create the distance matrix D associated to your data set, use scipy.spatial.distance_matrix and take as x the small subset of your data set and as y the whole data set.
2. Create a list, neighbors = []
3. Loop over the i'th row of the distance matrix. If D(i,j) < epsilon, then save j in neighbors. It is the index of a data point in the epsilon neighborhood of i.
4. Return neighbors

Of course the computation of the distance matrix should happen once at the beginning (maybe in **init**() if you wrap everything up in a class), and the function/method that returns all epsilon neighbors of a data point should only depend on the index of the data point in question.

Hope this helps!